# Run workflow with specified user's id in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have created two custom lists, L1 and L2 with same columns, listed below.

```
Title(Single line of text) 
Name(Single line of text)
```

I've written a workflow that copies the newly created item from L1 to L2 using "copy list item" action of workflow. The user who is creating a new item in L1 has contributor access on it but he has no access on L2. This is why I get an error in workflow.

Can I run the workflow with an another id which has at least contributor access in L2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the ability to impersonate a user in a sharepoint designer workflow. Add the impersonation around the copy list item action and if the impersonated user has access it should work

Edit: To create an Impersonation Step...

1. Open up your workflow and click the Edit Workflow button to build it out.
2. Click either **outside** the Step 1 box or the **Step 1** text
3. On the Ribbon there is a section labeled Insert; the Impersonation Step on the bottom right of that section should now be selectable
4. Click on Impersonation Step to add a section that will be run ***under the workflow author's credentials***

Let me know if you have any questions on this

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you please provide me some more information on this. Please excuse me for this, I am very new to SharePoint.

Comment: Updated the answer, please take a look and let me know if that is sufficient